# Receive xml result from server

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Under qt, I post a query to server using QTcpSocket. 
I will receive an xml result.
I use QLabel to display xml content.

I have tried like this.

```
QDataStream ini(&sock);
QString result;
in >> result;
ui->label->setText(result);
```

I'm sorry that I cant provide result, because stackoverflow don't allow me post images.

But I got some messy code instead of xml. What's the reason?

Sometimes I can receive some http response words though very rare.
And I will appreciate if you can tell me how to do it.

Perhaps it's how I display xml content made messy code. I'm confused.:)

Comment: Can you edit your question to add an example of the "messy code", and maybe how it should be?

Comment: It's some unreadable code, absolutely meaningless. I cant post images yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The data from the server is not in datastream format. So you cannot read it using QDatastream. Use sock->read()/sock->readAll() directly instead.

2) Make sure you use the QLabel in plain text mode:

```
label->setTextFormat( Qt::PlainText )
```

Using a QTextBrowser (also, with setPlainText) would be more useful though and will give you more readable and easier to navigate output.